# Will reloading supervisord cause the process under its to stop?

Tags: python, reload, supervisord

I try to figure out when I used reload command to supervisord. Will it stop the processing currently executing under it?
I used below steps:

```
mlzboy@mlzboy-mac:~/my/ide/test$ pstree -p|grep super
        |-supervisord(6763)
mlzboy@mlzboy-mac:~/my/ide/test$ supervisorctl 
daemon                           STARTING   
supervisor> reload
Really restart the remote supervisord process y/N? y
Restarted supervisord
supervisor> exit
mlzboy@mlzboy-mac:~/my/ide/test$ pstree -p|grep super
        |-supervisord(6763)
```

I found that the process id is not changed. So does it prove reload will not stop the processing under supervisor control?

Comment: i figure it out by myself,it will kill all subporcess,also i made a mistake the verb reload in nginx vs supervisor,in nginx it means reload configuration,in supervisor it means restart,the equivalent verb is update.but why the pid not changed , i'm still confused,any one could explain it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It doesn't kill the supervisord process, it just stops all processes, reload the configuration file, and restart processes again.

If you just want to apply the new configurations use `reread` command. It'd just reload the configuration without stopping, and respawning processes.

And running `update` will restart the processes (groups) that have changed.

Comment: it seems the xml-rpc didn't provide reread or update api for remote control http://supervisord.org/api.html?highlight=rpc#supervisor.xmlrpc, is there any way i can remote control ,not through supervisorctl

Comment: sorry for my carefulless,i find it,but i encounter another problem,how can know the current supervisor use which config file,because i have lots of conf file for test,dev etc,i can't distinguish them,unless know the current using conf file location,then i can check it